# ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to migrate data from Oracle table over to MariaDB table.  I have csv files from the Oracle table unload and a load script to load these files into corresponding mariadb tables which I have created using the same table/schema definition as it is in Oracle side.  I am getting the 1062 (230000) Duplicate entry error however I don't understand why MySQL/Mariadb treats the data as unique?  The value in the 1st record which gets inserted is in lower case and in the 2nd insert which fails is in uppercase.  It seems that both mysql and mariadb are treating the value the same and hence I am getting the Duplicate entry error for primary key. In order to show my error, I have created a test table and manually attempted to insert 2 rows.  I have put all the relevant info below and would appreciate if there is some explanation.  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
MariaDB [mytestdb]>  create table test1 (id char(15) not null, recnum integer, primary key(id));

MariaDB [mytestdb]> show create table test1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: test1
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `test1` (
  `id` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `recnum` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

MariaDB [mytestdb]> insert into test1 values ('abc123',1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [mytestdb]> insert into test1 values ('ABC123',2);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'ABC123' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Thanks,
Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

MySQL isn't case sensitive by default. You should define the column with one of the COLLATION options (*_cs) suitable for the datatype, or if none exists, the _bin collation. Or, if all else fails (eg, the _cs or _bin collations for your datatype don't exist), you may need to set the column to BINARY charset instead.

As a starting point, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html might be useful.

Comment: Jon, thank you for your reply. I tried using the latin1_bin for COLLATE value and this worked in my test table.  I was able to insert the 2 rows in my example.  I will try it out on the real table as I have confidence that it will work. Thanks & Regards, Sanjay

Comment: No worries! Just remember you've done this if you start doing queries with joins against this column: you'll need to make sure the character set and collation matches or sometimes MySQL will throw away the index and just do a full table scan.